# How to show the list of Subsites in a Site Collection in a 3 column format in SharePoint 2013 Site Collection landing page?

Tags: sharepoint-server

How to show the list of Subsites in a Site Collection in a 3 column format in SharePoint 2013 Site Collection landing page?

for example:

Subsite1      Subsite6        Subsite11

Subsite2      Subsite7        Subsite12

Subsite3      Subsite8        Subsite13

Subsite4      Subsite9        Subsite14

Subsite5      Subsite10       Subsite15

Kindly let me know which Web Part I have to use in order to show the list of Subsites in a Site Collection in a 3 column format

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you have any OOTB webpart which cater your requirement. You might need to build a custom webpart, which holds custom code may be in JavaScript or C#.

Comment: Use content search web part and implement the  all the  subsites from the site collection,  enter the querytext in the right pane's of this web part .

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned code in custom webpart to get SubSites from site collection. Yo can get all site collection names in table as per your desired output which you want.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    //To get all subsites, use this two lines
    SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPWebCollection collWebs = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;

    //To get first subsites, use this two lines
    //SPWeb oWebsiteColl = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url).OpenWeb();
    //SPWebCollection collWebs = oWebsiteColl.Webs;

    foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebs)
    {
        using (oWebsite)
        {
           string WebURL = oWebsite.ServerRelativeUrl;
           //Code here to aarange them in table as per your need.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: above code is heavy and uses  custom visual web part . best way is to use content search web part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API for this, you can use jquery to create tables and add the result in each cell

In order to get the list of sub sites from a site we need to call the below URL:

```
/_api/site/rootWeb/webinfos
```

Now to get the entire site structure we will need to loop every site to see if there are any sub sites present.

Below is the code I have used.

//The First Ajax is to get the Root Site Title and the Relative URL

```
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + “/_api/site/rootweb?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl”,
method: “GET”,
headers: {
“Accept”: “application/json; odata=verbose”
},
success: function(rootsite) {

},
error: function(rootsite) {},
async: false
});
```

// The Second AJAX is to get all the sub sites under the Root Site

```
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + “/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title”,
method: “GET”,
headers: {
“Accept”: “application/json; odata=verbose”
},
success: function(subsites) {
$.each(subsites.d.results, function() {
getSubSites(this.ServerRelativeUrl, this.Title);
});

},
error: function(subsites) {},
async: false
});
```

// This is a Recursive Function to loop through the sub sites and check for more sub sites

```
function getSubSites(SubSiteUrl, SubSiteTitle) {
console.log(SubSiteUrl);
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + SubSiteUrl + “/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title”,
method: “GET”,
headers: {
“Accept”: “application/json; odata=verbose”
},
success: function(subsites) {

$.each(subsites.d.results, function(index) {
getSubSites(this.ServerRelativeUrl, this.Title);
});
},
error: function(subsites) {},
async: false
});
}
```

Reference link :

[Retrieve toplevel site's subsites using REST _api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92467/retrieve-toplevel-sites-subsites-using-rest-api)

http://dsouzajoel.com